# How to navigate to another page without re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I want something like this.
Example: Whenever I search for a product from a different page it should navigate to product page and it shouldn't rerender. Because if it rerender it would trigger componentDidMount and replace my searched items.

Here I dispatch the search keyword after finding the products I am pushing it to prebuilds page

```
 const onSearch = async(e) => {
    if(e.which === 13 && searchKeyword !== null || e.type === 'click' && searchKeyword !== null){
      await dispatch(searchProduct(searchKeyword))
      props.history.push('/Prebuilds')
    }
  }
```

When it navigates to this page it triggers componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.onInitPrebuilds()
  }
```

I tried using shouldComponentUpdate it didn't worked.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Because if it rerender it would trigger componentDidMount and replace my searched items."* Re-rendering doesn't trigger `componentDidMount`. *Mounting* does. Re-rendering just re-renders.

Comment: oh okay then is there any way to solve my problem @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Hemanth you need to have a kind of global state or flag to maintain the filtered products if filter applied then ignore the onInitPrebuilds()